# JCombobox containing enum values inside a table

Tags: java, swing, enums, jcombobox

I have a class containing Enum with values. (names)
In other class I would like to enter inside a table a cell type of JCombobox that will use these enums values.
my problem is to combain between string values and the enum.
for example the enum class:

> > enum item_Type {entree, main_Meal, Dessert, Drink}

for example the table class:
setTitle("Add new item" );
        setSize(300, 80);
        setBackground( Color.gray );

```
    // Create a panel to hold all other components
    topPanel = new JPanel();
    topPanel.setLayout( new BorderLayout() );
    getContentPane().add( topPanel );

    //new JComboBox(item_Type.values());
    JComboBox aaa = new JComboBox();
    aaa = new JComboBox(item_Type.values());
    TableColumn sportColumn = table.getColumnModel().getColumn(2);

    // Create columns names
    String columnNames[] = {"Item Description", "Item Type", "Item Price"};

    // Create some data
    String dataValues[][] = {{ "0", aaa, "0" }};
    // Create a new table instance
    table = new JTable( dataValues, columnNames );

    // Add the table to a scrolling pane
    scrollPane = new JScrollPane( table );
    topPanel.add( scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER );
```

I know that at the dataValues array I cant use aaa (the enum jcombobox).
How can I do that?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set a [TableCellEditor](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableCellEditor.html) on the `JTable` to display the combo box.

```
TableColumn column = table.getColumnModel().getColumn(2);
column.setCellEditor(new DefaultCellEditor(aaa));
```

In your `dataValues` array, just use a placeholder for the combo box:

```
String dataValues[][] = {{ "0", "entree", "0" }};
```

You will, of course, need to set the column editor **after** creating the table:

```
String dataValues[][] = {{ "0", "entree", "0" }};
JTable table = new JTable(dataValues, columnNames);
TableColumn column = table.getColumnModel().getColumn(2);
column.setCellEditor(new DefaultCellEditor(aaa));
```

I highly recommend that you take a look at the [How to Use Tables](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) tutorial, if you haven't already. It explains this in greater detail, and includes sample code.